# From fixed point to floating point

Tags: c#, .net

As input to my algorithm I get integer values which are scaled by 10. So if I get 10 it is actually 1, if I get 1 it is actually 0.1. I need to convert it to fractional representation for calculations and then convert back for output. I guess if I convert numbers to double there is a risk to loose some accuracy during convertations. What is the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: What are your accuracy requirements? That will determine what "the right way to solve this problem" is.

Comment: have you considered using a [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Comment: Requirements is that I shoud not loose any accuracy during these convertations.

Comment: Any? I think you need to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to gain an understanding of what is and isn't possible.

Comment: Also, what are these integer values being used for in the code that calls your algorithm? That may also have a bearing on the solution.

Comment: @Idsa: "not loose any accuracy" is an impossible requirement to meet. All computer numeric storage formats have limits on their accuracy. What we need to know is what limits are acceptable and what are unacceptable to *you*.

Comment: @ChristianHayter, but what about fixed-point values?

Comment: @Idsa: I suggest you read Oded's link, then try to add some more detail to your question so that we can help you. There is no one data type that will magically solve your problem. We need to know what your requirements are in much greater detail than you have given so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [decimal type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) offers higher accuracy (than floating point) for 10-base calculations, and that's what I would use.

Comment: or, alternatively, simply __ajust your calculation__ to use the scaled version?